# Can't install winget with Add-AppxProvisionedPackage: Specified module not found

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2022

I'm running Windows server 2022 Core and i need to install winget. Since winget needs UI.xaml and vclibs i installed them from nuget and microsoft website. For UI.xaml i had to unpack so i could get `.appx` installer. Winget and its license file is from latest release on github.
Here is my command:

```
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath .\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle -LicensePath .\license1.xml -DependencyPackagePath .\vclibs.appx,.\xaml\tools\AppX\x64\Release\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.7.appx
```

Yet when i try to run it fails with:

```
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage : Не найден указанный модуль.
строка:1 знак:1
+ Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath .\Microsoft.DesktopAp ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-AppxProvisionedPackage], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.AddAppxProvisionedPackageCommand
```

`Не найден указанный модуль` means `Specified module not found`, so i don't really understand which module it needs.
Also if i try to install any of these with `Add-AppxPackage` it fails with unique errors for them.
UI.Xaml and VClibs:

```
Add-AppxPackage : Сбой развертывания с HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Не удалось зарегистрировать пакет.
Ошибка 0x80040154: не удается зарегистрировать запрос, так как при инициализации расширения windows.capability произошла следующая ошибка: Класс не зарегистрирован.
ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Чтобы получить дополнительные сведения, найдите [ActivityId] f43d73af-5f07-0000-77d73df4075fda01 в журнале событий или введите в командной строке Get-AppxLog -ActivityID f43d73af5f07-0000-77d7-3df4075fda01.
строка:1 знак:1
+ Add-AppxPackage .\xaml\tools\AppX\x64\Release\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.7.a ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\user\...I.Xaml.2.7.appx:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

I've also tried to install it with [this module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/winget-install/4.0.1), but sadly it also fails with `Specified module not found`.
[This article](https://4sysops.com/archives/install-winget-on-windows-server-and-activate-preview-features/) shows installation one by one, but as i said it doesn't work since `Add-AppxPackage` fails because of `windows.capability` and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/carey/62070ee199099c4233f572a17315366d) shows installation as i've tried it, it also done the same way in winget-install script.
I expected powershell to install winget, so i could create a ansible playbook

Comment: This won't help much, but [`0x80073CF6`](https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_WIN32/0x80073CF6) means "Package could not be registered."

Comment: Also not sure if it helps, but the [instructions for installing on Windows Sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/#install-winget-on-windows-sandbox) are worth a look.

Comment: Great to see that i can install UI.xaml without extracting anything, but at the end i still get error `0x80073CF6`.